# return the value of the list by elements's name not index in C#

Tags: c#

I have a getvalue object that contains a price list which consists of 5 items. I need to get the value of one of the elements. I can get the value by index:

```
  return (getValue1.ValuationPrices[4].Value.ToString());
```

Instead of using 4 (the index) I would like to use the name of the field. How Can I do that?

More details:

[image]

I want to say if PriceType is "Wholesale" return the value that is 18289

That is the solution to this question:

```
     foreach (var item in getValue1.ValuationPrices)
            {
                if (item.PriceType == ServiceReference1.PriceType.Wholesale)
                {

                    carValue= item.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Update your old question with new informations,instead of asking new question

Comment: I have updated there but beacuse they have to click on link nobody does that can you pleaseeee delete that one, here is much better as image comes in the page.

Comment: You have answers in your original question. You'd get exactly the same ones on this one - `Enumerable.First` or manual `for`... If you have problem comparing values you need to ask different question.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, but still I haven't got answer.    if(getValue1.ValuationPrices.Any(s=>s.PriceType.???"Wholesale")) what should I have insetad of ???

Comment: So ask question like "I have field of type `enum BlaBla`, how I can compare the field to `BlaBla.Wholesale`. Would `==` work for `enum`?" instead of creating seemingly exact duplicate.